# Spark Kryo Serialization fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

I have a piece of Spark code that worked on Spark 1.3 but fails when I move it to Spark 1.5.2 (cluster upgrade out of my control). The failure is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.location.model.Profile
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.location.model.Profile, value: com.location.model.Profile@596032b0)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1, name: zeroValue$3, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1, <function0>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1$$anonfun$1, <function0>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1$$anonfun$apply$10, name: createZero$1, type: interface scala.Function0)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1$$anonfun$apply$10, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
```

The interesting piece is that the class at hand, `Profile`, is declared as `class Profile() extends KryoSerializable` and overrides the read/write methods for that interface.

I've also set this config to Spark-submit: `"--conf" -> "'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer'"` and registered the `Profile` class with Kryo by doing `conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(
      classOf[Profile], ...`

So all according to instruction in the [Spark Tunning guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/tuning.html#data-serialization), and it worked nicely before. 
Note that the exception shows a `JavaSerializerInstance` being used by the `ClosureCleaner`, and indeed if I add `extends Serializable` to the `Profile` class it works. But I'm not sure why it is using that serializer nor why should I be compatible with Java Serialization if I'm specifically asking for Kryo.

---

Edit: I even removed the parameter altogether, since the code under `registerKryoClasses` sets the property in any case. In fact, I suspect Kryo serialization is being used (I added a println inside `write` and it appears, but some kind of previous validation is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove ' from your submit, imho it should be

--conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"

do you submit from luigi by any chance?

Comment: I was asking about removig single quotes that wrap your conf param and not removing it completely

Comment: Same effect, you are basically stating if the configuration is being set properly.

Comment: yes, indeed. another point I can think of - why do you register Array of Profile and not Profile itself ? - it seems that spark has problems with some closure that has Profile as param(from stacktrace)

Comment: I do not. `registerKryoClasses` expects and array of classes to be registered. `Profile` is just the first of those classes. What you mention would look like `classOf[Array[Profile]]`. I appreciate the help though :-)

Comment: and sadly, there is no closure involved, the line 107 is in fact `.aggregateByKey(new Profile(), 3200)`, I'm just providing a zero value :-(